# if statement doesn't work on fetch request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a pagination function and sometimes the response is empty and the API returns the following code

```
{
  "code": "rest_post_invalid_page_number",
  "message": "Le nombre de page demandé est plus grand que le nombre de pages disponibles.",
  "data": {
    "status": 400
  }
}
```

so to handle this error I made an if statement but it doesnt work it goes straight to return JSON

```
pagination = (mode) => {
      fetch(url)
        .then((response) => {
          if (!response.data.status === 400) {
            return response.json();
          } else {
         this.setState({error: 'pagination error'})
         }
        })
        .then((data) => {
          this.setState({
            data: data,
            done: true,
            loading: false,
            page: this.state.page + 1,
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("error :", error);
          this.setState({
            error: error.toString(),
            loading: false,
          });
        });
  };
```

I also included the code in `.then(data)` I am getting the same issue

What get triggered is the `catch` error at the end

Comment: You can perform your operation based on `statusCode`

Comment: Don't call `setState` on the error, re-throw instead, otherwise the promise chain is going to continue,  so replace the setState with `throw new Error('pagination error')` end then your default error handler will handle the setState..

Comment: @Keith How do I avoid the chain to continue, I dont want return JSON if code error 400, because there's no page left

Comment: Do what I just said, it's not going to return any json, as it won't get to the next `then`, but jump to the `catch`..

Answer (score 0):

If the server sets the HTTP status properly, you should directly check `response.status` or `response.ok`.

```js
if (response.status !== 400)
// or
if (response.ok) // status in the range 200-299
```

Comment: Thats's the right syntax of inverse I was inverting the variable rather the result

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is possibly from `response.data.status`, you don't get data from `json()` but use a response object directly which never has `data.status` as you expected.

A possible fix could be

```
pagination = (mode) => {
      fetch(url)
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json(); //make sure data is converted
        })
        .then((data) => {
          if (!data.status === 400) {
            return data;
          } else {
           this.setState({error: 'pagination error'});
           return null;
         }
        })
        .then((data) => {

          if(data) {
             return null;
          }
 
          this.setState({
            data: data,
            done: true,
            loading: false,
            page: this.state.page + 1,
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("error :", error);
          this.setState({
            error: error.toString(),
            loading: false,
          });
        });
  };
```